# GC Committed Bytes what does it meant?

Tags: c#, .net-core, garbage-collection, .net-7.0

I was practicing in app memory profiling. I have an ASP.NET Core 7 MVC app running on Ubuntu. I notice that some memory wasn't released, so I've tried to use `dotnet-counters monitor -p <pid>` to see what's going on here and found some strange values like `GC Committed Byte` is huge.

I don't understand what that means. How can I interpret result to understand way for further investigation?

I couldn't find any information in the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/dotnet-counters) that would help me explain the meaning of this counter and how to interpret it.

`dotnet-counters` output example:

```
[System.Runtime]
% Time in GC since last GC (%)                                         0
Allocation Rate (B / 1 sec)                                        8,168
CPU Usage (%)                                                          0.015
Exception Count (Count / 1 sec)                                        0
GC Committed Bytes (MB)                                            1,269.08
GC Fragmentation (%)                                                  54.622
GC Heap Size (MB)                                                     19.337
Gen 0 GC Count (Count / 1 sec)                                         0
Gen 0 Size (B)                                                         0
Gen 1 GC Count (Count / 1 sec)                                         0
Gen 1 Size (B)                                                   554,856
Gen 2 GC Count (Count / 1 sec)                                         0
Gen 2 Size (B)                                                27,092,392
IL Bytes Jitted (B)                                            2,410,959
LOH Size (B)                                                   8,032,824
Monitor Lock Contention Count (Count / 1 sec)                          0
Number of Active Timers                                                5
Number of Assemblies Loaded                                          158
Number of Methods Jitted                                          29,767
POH (Pinned Object Heap) Size (B)                              3,765,072
ThreadPool Completed Work Item Count (Count / 1 sec)                   0
ThreadPool Queue Length                                                0
ThreadPool Thread Count                                                4
Time spent in JIT (ms / 1 sec)                                         0
Working Set (MB)                                                   1,552.4
```

Comment: 1.2 GB of committed bytes is indeed big comparing to a dozen of MBs for the managed heap. What kind of app is it? Does it use any external libraries that may utilize unmanaged memory? And BTW - what are the machine specs (cpus/RAM)?

Comment: @KonradKokosa machine specs: RAM = 8GB, CPUs = 4x3393MHz.
About app: it's simple CRUD app but can generate ZIP archives for user with data (from DBs + include files on disk from server). I start thinking problem can be in `MemoryStream` using. I use it for creating Zip on fly without saving on disk temporary files.